# Prefill PHP web form

Tags: php, web, url, webforms

I need to complete the same webpage form with different information (I need to register all members of a group on a website).

So I want to do a small script that would generate me some URL, each one opening the registration web page with the form prefilled with each member name, email.....

I tried to do so on rakuten connect page and it works, if I load the web page using https://fr.shopping.rakuten.com/connect?auth_user_identifier=foo.gmail.com (`auth_user_identifier` being the `id` of the `email` field) then the email field is prefilled.

However, on the webpage I need to work with it does not work. The site is in php and it does not work as expected. The site needs an authentication so I can't link it here but I could reproduce the issue on tryphp web site:

https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_form_validation_complete&email=toto

This link opens the page but does not prefill the email form with `toto` while the field `id` seems correct.

Any idea what should be the URL parameters to have email field be prefilled?

Comment: Well if the code behind the page does not expect inputs in the querystring or just does not attempt to pre load the form fields even if they exist in the querystring, there is not much you can do

Comment: You mean I was lucky with the rakuten website because its code was expected the field to be possibly set from the URL?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. There is no default that says that should be done

Comment: Not even a browser plugin could help, for chrome or Firefox or any other browser I could install....?

Comment: On your example you in W3Schools you are using $_POST['name'] for example to be filled by a URL ?name=someone is that correct? if so the code should be $_GET['name'] to prefill your fields... $_POST is after a post has been made.

Comment: @Shlomtzion I'm not using $_GET nor $_POST, I'm just trying to fill the form from the URL arguments

Answer (score 1):

Putting in the values as `$_GET` parameters only works if the website expects them to be there. For example, the website may echo the `$_GET` parameter in the `value` attribute of the input.

But there's really no way of knowing if this will work unless you try.

If you're looking to automate filling forms and submitting them on a website, I'd like to recommend [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). It's a python package that can be used to automate various browser tasks.

[This](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-python-and-selenium-to-automate-filling-forms-and-mouse-clicks-f87c74ed5c0f) is a tutorial that shows how to fill and submit a form pretty accurately.

The best way would probably be to create a dictionary or load a json file into a dictionary and then loop over the entries and submit the form.